# How to change data type of PK for very min to no maintenance while performing this action

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, alter-table

We had issue on our prod server for one of the tables approx 500 M rows and one of the column int has maxed out its length limit. So probable suggestion from dev team was to change data type of that column from int to Bigint. this column is PK for that table.

Per plan we are dropping the constraint and then use ALTER statement to change data type. But every time its a unsuccessful because of issues it creates like a long blocking chain due to volume and hence we end up canceling after the change struggling to complete for couple of hours.

I worked with app team on diff windows but its same issue. seems like we do not have a proper window to get this done.

I would like to know the best approach on how to do this in prod and what wrong we might be doing here. Please advise or refer to any blog post.

I am reading https://am2.co/2019/12/changing-a-column-from-int-to-bigint-without-downtime/ which seems for SQL2016+ but unfortunately i am on 2014 so cant use ONLINE option

Thanks

Comment: @MBuschi - Not really and would be challenging involving storage team and lot of additional request to approve if we go with approach of moving data to new table and then delete old one, unless its the only good option for us

Comment: Why not schedule a planned long enough maintenance break? On the other hand, if you don't and int runs out, you will have an unplanned maintenance break on possibly very inconvinient time.

Comment: If you can't make a downtime window, the solution in the article you found using a new table and a trigger may work.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft- Thanks for the input.  I am having a discussion with my devs over same. so when we say downtime, should any calls specific to that table be not made while other load can still be running ? just trying to understand how we define this downtime or entire instance needs to have its volume stopped till the time operation is moving?

Comment: Hi @Newbie-DBA, if you search for "The last step is the one that is slightly disruptive." in the article you linked to, that's the section where I discuss the disruptive step of the new table/trigger option, so you can determine what considerations you'll need to take for your database & application.